# Node.js with Firebase create user

Tags: node.js, firebase

Please, I am trying to use node with firebase but I am running into a few issues. I am not sure what it is. When I try creating a user without trying to create a document in the user's collection. It works.

Now when I added lines 23 - 34 I got the following error:

```
router.post('/signup',async (req, res, next)=>{
//probably in the request there will be some data
//create user in the system
console.log('INSIDE SIGN UP');
const userResponse = await database.auth().createUser({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    emailVerified: false,
    disabled: false
})
res.json(userResponse);

//create user in the table with extra properties
const userDoc = {
    firebaseId: userResponse.uid,
    username: '',
    profilePic: ''
}
db.collection('users').add(userDoc).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('opps there was an error');
    console.log(err);
});
```

});

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am trying to create the user and add a document to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to enable Firestore in your Firebase project. To do so, login to your Firebase console at https://console.firebase.google.com, click on Firestore Database in the sidebar under Build, and follow the steps to create your database.

The createUser function is succeeding because you have set up Firebase Authentication, which is a separate product from Firestore; Firestore is a database product.